# How to stop a timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have the following action performed method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Object source = e.getSource();

    String stringfromDate = tffromDate.getText();
    String stringtoDate = tftoDate.getText();

    if (source == button) {
        // auto refresh begins
        int delay = 0; // 0 seconds startup delay
        int period = 7000; // x seconds between refreshes
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            // i still have to truly understand what overide does however
            // netbeans prompted me to put this
            public void run() {

                try {
                    getdata(stringfromDate, stringtoDate);// run get data
                                                            // method
                } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication63.class.getName())
                            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    if (source == button1) {
        timer.cancel();

        textarea.setText("");
    }
}
```

I have 2 buttons on my GUI one called get information(button) and another called clear information (button1).
I cant seem to get my clear information(button1) to stop the timer and clear the text area so that a new search can be performed. I just cant seem to get this to stop help appreciated.

Comment: Can you format your code properly so that we can actually read it? Indent it and such?

Comment: Looks like you are creating a new Timer object each time your method is called, so of course you cannot access the previous timer. Move that Timer declaration to the class, i.e., make it a member instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these changes to your code. Mainly the code does these things differently:

- Pull up the declaration of your timer into the class, so that the same timer started before can be cancelled later.
- only create a new timer if the start-button was pressed.

  ```
  //Pulled up for access to make canceable .
  protected Timer timer;

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();

    String stringfromDate = tffromDate.getText();
    String stringtoDate = tftoDate.getText();

    if (source == button) {
      //Stop existing one before creating new.
      if(timer != null) {
          timer.cancel();
      }
      //Now make new
      timer = new Timer();

      // auto refresh begins
      int delay = 0; // 0 seconds startup delay
      int period = 7000; // x seconds between refreshes
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override 
          public void run() {

              try {
                  getdata(stringfromDate, stringtoDate);// run get data
                                                          // method
              } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication63.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

              }

          }
      }, delay, period);
    }
    if (source == button1) {          
      //NULLCHECK
      if(timer != null) {
          timer.cancel();
      }
      textarea.setText("");
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Actually, @LittleSanti, I have no clue what `button` is - I assume that't the "start" button. But if I counted { correctly, is *is* happening in that `if`?!

Comment: @ Jan i have just tried your suggestion it doesnt appear to work, button is the start button, and then button1 is the stop button to clear the timer process and clear the text...could it be that the button click of the clear information (button1) isnt registered as a click while the thread is active?

Comment: I'd need to see more code (like how you register the actionListener and stuff) to check that. If you're unsure which branch your code is running through generously apply System.out("Now I'm in source == button1") and the like to your code or use a debugger.

Comment: @ Jan i got it to work now i was just missing a curly bracket, many thanks for your help